# Part of JQUERY functions not working IE 9 and IE 10

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-9, internet-explorer-10

My Jquery functions are not working in IE9 and 10 except for Jquery Autosuggest. However the same is working in IE 8 and 7 as well as other Browsers like Chrome and FireFox.

I have used the following Jquery Plugins in the same page

```
.."http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
       ../accountuser/js/jquery-1.7.2-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
       ../accountuser/js/1.8.jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Pls advice where I went wrong..

** I tried one version alone. But the issue is same. The code works perfectly in IE8 and 7 **

Awaiting your valuable reply

Many Thanks

Comment: Which jQuery version are you using?

Comment: I just updated my query

Comment: Do you use all 3 jQuery versions in same page? don't.

Comment: But an Accordion used in the Page needs query-1.7.2-min.js

Comment: Use just 1 version. The latest and under 2.0 which does not support older IE versions anymore.

Comment: Ie 9 and above have undergone many changes, this features are not added in 1.x jQuery, This features are available in jquery 2.x. For ie 6 ,7 and 8 use 1.x and ie 9, above  use 2.x

Comment: @niko: That's not correct. jQuery 1.x is for any version of IE. jQuery doesn't add features specific to a few new browsers. They did however remove support for old browsers in 2.x.

Comment: I used a single version but still no luck. But the accountuser/js/1.8.jquery-ui.min.js functionality is working in all browsers

Answer (score 1):

I managed the situation by adding this in the head tag.

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" >
```

Since everything works well in IE8.. But still seeking a possible solution.

Thanks for all your time and suggestions

Comment: I've got the same problem here. Already found an other solution?

Comment: Has anyone found any solution to this? I'm having the very same problem here